# exact short sequence of divisible groups splits?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, abelian-groups

Let $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequences of divisible abelian groups. Does then the sequence splits?

Comment: This has nothing to do with algebraic geometry or linear algebra (although it may have applications in those areas), so it was not a good idea to add those tags. The commutative algebra tag that you started with was quite appropriate. Further, this looks more like a homework problem than it does a research problem, so it would probably be more suitable on MathStackExchange.

Comment: Since you used the ac tag, the keyword is "injective module". So, one half is the notion and basic properties of injective modules. The second half is that a divisible module over a PID is injective. Nothing very specific to abelian groups (i.e. modules over the specific ring $\mathbf{Z}$).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because due to divisibility, $A$ is a direct summand in $B$, that is the embedding of $A$ into $B$ has a left inverse; this is the [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma).

Comment: Can you explain how can one reach a left inverse? this is exactly what is confusing me.

Comment: @user350168 see Theorem 21.2 in Fuchs' Infinite Abelian Groups.